# can't run 2 individually guild and direct message "ready" event / discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm intent on adding 2 "ready" events to my Discord bot. I think that would be probably fine because I've added more than one "interactionCreate" event before. So basically one event (1) will send a message to the guild and the other one (2) will send a message to the DMs. Anyways these are my codes (I've followed [this discord guide on sending a message to the channel](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel) and [this discord guide on sending a private message](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-dm-a-specific-user)):

> (1)
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>    name: 'ready',
>    once: true,
>    async execute(client) {    
>        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('ChannelID');
>        ...
>        channel.send(`${todaySession.join(", ")}`);
>        ...
> };
> ```

> (2)
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>    name: 'ready',
>    once: true,
>    async execute(client) {    
>        const user = await client.users.fetch('UserID'); 
>         console.log(user);
>         user.send(" ");
> };
> ```

sometimes it works but mostly it will throw this error (there's 15 page total of the error so i'm not gonna post it on here ofc):

```js
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

<ref *1> Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
```

I've done a variety of research though, but it seems too complicated for me (because I casually understand a part of WebSocket)
I'll put it down here in case you guys found something that i've missed.

> 1/ [ECONNRESET usually means the internet connection dies somewhere along the way, there's nothing much the lib can do about it.](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3043)
>
> 2/ [the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753507/is-there-any-way-to-stop-econnreset-error-from-crashing-my-bot)
>
> 3/ [bot goes ded](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/e7wigd/i_run_a_discord_bot_using_nodejs_and_every_few/)

My temporary solution here is to implement all of the event into a-one-but-only "ready" event file so it can work like a charm. Besides, is there any explanation for this and how can we solve this for good ?